# Load usercontrol on postback and load data based on parent page textbox value c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, postback

This is probably really simple, but I cant seem to get my values picked up at all from the parent page?

Aspx page is within a master page and ContentPwith the code for example

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbFromDate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="butDisplayInfo" runat="server" Text="Display info" OnClick="butDisplayInfo_Click"
        CssClass="button-gray" />
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolderContent" runat="server">              
   </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

What I want is when the button is pressed it loads the UserControl and loads data based on the date put in the text box which I can then use to load data to the control?

.aspx.cs

```
protected void butDisplayInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = LoadControl("~/Controls/DailyShiftStats.ascx");
    ctrl.ID = "ucUserCtrl1";

    placeHolderContent.Controls.Add(ctrl);
}
```

Usercontrol ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.Parent.Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("tbFromDate");
            Response.Write(tb.Text); 
}

public void getShiftInfo(DateTime shiftDate)
{
    //load my data
}
```

Comment: Why should the Control need to know anything about the Page? How would you then re-use the control? You would be better creating a property on the UserControl and then passing the date to it IMHO.

Comment: Any advice on how best to do this would be great please, as I have tried this method, but I just end up getting 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment - you would be better defining a property in your control and then have the page pass this in, I have not done this in a while but the basic idea is -

In your control

```
public DateTime? ShiftDate
{
    set { this.shiftDate = value; }
}
private DateTime? shiftDate;
```

Then you can use shiftDate anywhere in your control where it is needed, if you make it Nullable as above then you can check to see if it has been set and throw an error (or whatever is appropriate) if not.

In your page when creating your control you would then have (Note: you need to cast your control to correct type)

```
var ctrl = (DailyShiftStats)LoadControl("~/Controls/DailyShiftStats.ascx");
ctrl.ID = "ucUserCtrl1";

//TODO: Handle an invalid date
DateTime shiftDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(tbFromDate.Text, out shiftDate))
{
    ctrl.ShiftDate = shiftDate;
}

placeHolderContent.Controls.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this wont build as it cant find 'ctrl.ShiftDate'. I get 'System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'ShiftDate' and no extension method 'ShiftDate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: See my edit - you need to cast to correct control type